# Having troubling identifying the CSS and pulling the right CSS from a Web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to re-create the "card-deck" class which contains eight cards, displayed on this page: https://www.portland.gov/transportation . While I was able to copy the html(by inspecting the card-deck class) , I am not sure how to find the CSS for the `class="card-deck"`.
Here is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LeamJack/dnwgrxtk/1/ . As you can see,I have the html for the card-deck class, but what is the efficient way of getting the CSS just for the the card-deck class?

Comment: You can find css files in `style editor` tab of firefox developer options.look for `.card-deck` rule in those files.

Comment: If you only need the CSS of a single element, right click on the element, click "Inspect Element" and depending on your browser you should see a section of the dev tools that shows all CSS properties of the selected element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inspect the element using most browsers.

For example in Chrome, you can right-click on one of the card elements and click `Inspect`. The DevTools panel will open, from there you can choose any element on the page and see it's css.

I can see the `card-panel` class has the following css:

```
.card-deck {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Then each of the nested cards have their own css that you'll have to replicate.

Additionally, you can see in the `<head>` element they are linking to two css files.

```
https://www.portland.gov/sites/default/files/css/css_Nap32wA4jB85LBZMJhLbUh8juJthC1U6LI-74yu_d5Y.css
```

and

```
https://www.portland.gov/sites/default/files/css/css_z4fhgF_myzmhopAFzinwvvWR4bdcPakuk6TPD5OyoaY.css
```

you can copy these files to a code beautifier like https://beautifier.io/

then search for the `card-deck` class and copy the css from there. It looks like the 2nd stylesheet is the one with the css you are looking for:

This is all the card related css I found by quickly looking at the stylesheet in the beautifier:

Note: you probably don't need all of this css for what you are trying to do.

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #b3bdcc;
    border-radius: .25rem
}

.card>hr {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0
}

.card>.list-group {
    border-top: inherit;
    border-bottom: inherit
}

.card>.list-group:first-child {
    border-top-width: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
    border-top-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px)
}

.card>.list-group:last-child {
    border-bottom-width: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
    border-bottom-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px)
}

.card-body {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding: 1.25rem
}

.card-title {
    margin-bottom: .75rem
}

.card-subtitle {
    margin-top: -.375rem
}

.card-subtitle,
.card-text:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.card-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none
}

.card-link+.card-link {
    margin-left: 1.25rem
}

.card-header {
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b3bdcc
}

.card-header:first-child {
    border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px) 0 0
}

.card-header+.list-group .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top: 0
}

.card-footer {
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .03);
    border-top: 1px solid #b3bdcc
}

.card-footer:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 calc(.25rem - 1px) calc(.25rem - 1px)
}

.card-header-tabs {
    margin-bottom: -.75rem;
    border-bottom: 0
}

.card-header-pills,
.card-header-tabs {
    margin-right: -.625rem;
    margin-left: -.625rem
}

.card-img-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1.25rem
}

.card-img,
.card-img-bottom,
.card-img-top {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%
}

.card-img,
.card-img-top {
    border-top-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
    border-top-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px)
}

.card-img,
.card-img-bottom {
    border-bottom-right-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px);
    border-bottom-left-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px)
}

.card-deck .card {
    margin-bottom: 15px
}

@media(min-width:576px) {
    .card-deck {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px
    }

    .card-deck .card {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        flex: 1 0 0%;
        margin-right: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 15px
    }
}

.card-group>.card {
    margin-bottom: 15px
}

@media(min-width:576px) {
    .card-group {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-flow: row wrap
    }

    .card-group>.card {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        flex: 1 0 0%;
        margin-bottom: 0
    }

    .card-group>.card+.card {
        margin-left: 0;
        border-left: 0
    }

    .card-group>.card:not(:last-child) {
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0
    }

    .card-group>.card:not(:last-child) .card-header,
    .card-group>.card:not(:last-child) .card-img-top {
        border-top-right-radius: 0
    }

    .card-group>.card:not(:last-child) .card-footer,
    .card-group>.card:not(:last-child) .card-img-bottom {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0
    }

    .card-group>.card:not(:first-child) {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0
    }

    .card-group>.card:not(:first-child) .card-header,
    .card-group>.card:not(:first-child) .card-img-top {
        border-top-left-radius: 0
    }

    .card-group>.card:not(:first-child) .card-footer,
    .card-group>.card:not(:first-child) .card-img-bottom {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0
    }
}

.card-columns .card {
    margin-bottom: .75rem
}

@media(min-width:576px) {
    .card-columns {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
        -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
        column-gap: 1.25rem;
        orphans: 1;
        widows: 1
    }

    .card-columns .card {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%
    }
}

.card--featured--group,
.card--related--group {
    border: none;
    background: #234476;
    cursor: pointer
}

.card--featured--group h3 a,
.card--related--group h3 a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none
}

.card--featured--group h3 a:hover,
.card--related--group h3 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline
}

.card-body .field--name-bundle-fieldgroup,
.card-body .field--name-bundle-fieldnode,
.card-body .field--name-field-external-resource-type,
.card-body .field--name-field-page-type {
    font-size: medium;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #eff1f5
}

.node--type-news.node--view-mode-featured {
    cursor: pointer
}

.card {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 0
}

.card .card-img-top {
    background: #fff
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .card {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
        flex-direction: row-reverse
    }

    .card .card-img-top {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        flex: 1 0 480px
    }

    .card .card-body {
        flex-basis: 100%
    }
}

@media(min-width:576px) {
    .card-deck .card {
        display: block;
        flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
        max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
        margin-bottom: 30px
    }
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
    .card-deck .card {
        flex-basis: calc(33.33333% - 30px);
        max-width: calc(33.33333% - 30px)
    }

    .card-deck .card .card-img-top {
        flex-basis: inherit
    }
}

@media(min-width:576px) {
    .card-deck--2 .card {
        display: block;
        flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px);
        max-width: calc(50% - 30px);
        margin-bottom: 30px
    }
}

.node .card-img--featured .field--type-image,
.node .media--view-mode-featured .field--type-image img {
    margin: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below screenshot you can see the right panel showing up the corresponding dom element classes and the css file reffering this class next to it. You can find the classes for any dom element this way. You can click on the file link to get the entire css as well.

[image]